# Add extra scroll space of the bottom of an HTML sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a side bar based on an example on this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapse_sidebar). Instead of just words i am placing canvases inside for charts. My charts displays fine but the last chart just is just barely at the end of the page although its still readable it does not look good. I was wondering what would be the best way to add an extra empty scroll space at the bottom ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Take a look at a snip of the code from the tutorial , when you run it, open the sidebar, and scroll down, the last item seems to be cut. I would like to add an extra blank scroll space how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an empty div with some height.

```
<div style="height: 150px"></div>
```

or give the `<div class="main">` a padding-bottom of 150px. That should do the job.

Comment: adding padding to main is kinda destructive as it affects content inside the main, adding an empty div though with a height seems to work well